# Adding DBContext as parameter inside IServiceCollection Method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm working on an abstraction for a project and I need IServiceCollection, IConfiguration and DBContext to be added to the IServiceCollection Method.
Trying to use the GeneriContext didn't work in Services.AddDbContext<>.

please help

```
{
        public static IServiceCollection AddSmartMoneyService(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, GeneriContext dbContext)
        {
            var serverVersion = new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 29));
            string connectionStringBuider = String.Empty;
            var settings = new DBConfigurationSettings();

            configuration.GetSection("DBConfigurationSettings").Bind(settings);

            if (settings.Provider.Equals(ProviderEnum.MSSQL))
            {
                connectionStringBuider = $"Server={settings.Host};Port={settings.Port};Database={settings.DBName};User Id={settings.UserId};password={settings.Password}";
                services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionStringBuider, options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()));

                //Health Checks
                services.AddHealthChecks().AddSqlServer(connectionStringBuider);
            }
            if (settings.Provider.Equals(ProviderEnum.MYSQL))
            {
                connectionStringBuider = $"Server={settings.Host};Port={settings.Port};Database={settings.DBName};User={settings.UserId};Password={settings.Password}";
                services.AddDbContext<GeneriContext>(x => x.UseMySql(connectionStringBuider, serverVersion, options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()));
            }
            if (settings.Provider.Equals(ProviderEnum.POSTGRESQL))
            {
                connectionStringBuider = $"Server={settings.Host};Port={settings.Port};Database={settings.DBName};User={settings.UserId};Password={settings.Password}";
                services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<GeneriContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(connectionStringBuider));
            }
            if (settings.Provider.Equals(ProviderEnum.MONGODB))
            {
                connectionStringBuider = $"Server={settings.Host};Port={settings.Port};Database={settings.DBName};User={settings.UserId};Password={settings.Password}";
            }
            if (settings.Provider.Equals(ProviderEnum.ORACLE))
            {
                connectionStringBuider = $"Server={settings.Host};Port={settings.Port};Database={settings.DBName};User={settings.UserId};Password={settings.Password}";
            }
            return services;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it currently stands, your question needs more clarity. You will have to provide more details besides "Trying to use the GeneriContext didn't work in Services.AddDbContext<>" and posting a large block of code for us to understand what you are trying to accomplish and the actual problem is. Please update your question with more details and a more concise (and better formatted) code example.

Comment: Could you please share what is the current concern? Which part not working as expected as well as what expected assistance you are looking for?